# Reg: Kafka connector configuration

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka source connector configuration to produce data from a source table (Maria DB) into a Kafka topic. For some tables, I am using `mode='timestamp'` in the connect config.
I have two fields `created_timestamp` and `updated_timestamp`. I want to produce records as per `updated_timestamp` field. But there is a chance that the `updated_timestamp` field might contain `NULL` values.

Currently, I am using the NVL function in the query parameter to select `created_time` whenever `updated_timestamp` is `NULL`. But records not flown from source table to topic.

Kafka source connector configuration

curl -k -X POST https://:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "TEST_SOURCECONNECT","config": {"topic.prefix": "topic-name","connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://db ip","connection.user": "","connection.password": "","mode": "timestamp","query": "SELECT t.* from (SELECT *, IFNULL(updated_timestamp, created_timestamp) as custom_timestamp FROM TABLE) t","timestamp.column.name": "custom_timestamp","validate.non.null": "false","poll.interval.ms": 60000}}'

Comment: do you have a stack trace error to help a potential solution?

Comment: I am not getting any error, task is getting assigned for the connect worker. But data is not flowing from  source to kafka topic.

Comment: So your connector is been created and it is running. Can you verify that? Maybe it is the 60 seconds on the property `poll.interval.ms`?